# Hide Soft Keyboard after touching the background or the linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to hide the Soft Keyboard by touching the background or the linearlayout.
How can I do it?

Can anyone Help Me?
Please

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide keyboard when user taps anywhere else on the screen in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697499/hide-keyboard-when-user-taps-anywhere-else-on-the-screen-in-android)

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext/36786783#36786783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `onTouchEvent`

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.
                                                        INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide soft keyboard on `onClick` event of your root view

```
linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

As per suggested by the H Raval , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11656129/2930834) is the best solution.
function `setupUI` in the answer will iterate through your `ViewGroup` and add `onTouch` listener to every other view except `EditText` which is right way to call the code which hides the keyboard.

Code :-

```
public void setupUI(View view) {

    //Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard. 
    if(!(view instanceof EditText)) {

        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                hideSoftKeyboard(MyActivity.this); 
                return false; 
            } 

        }); 
    } 

    //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion. 
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {

            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);

            setupUI(innerView);
        } 
    } 
} 

public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```