# Screen flicker due to dispatchTouchEvent in activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I am using @Daniel answer [Keyboard Hide on Outside Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005728/hide-default-keyboard-on-click-in-android#) to hide keyboard on outside click of edittext and it works perfectly but it causes flickering of screen , if there a about 15-20 edittext and you scroll to bottom from a focused editext(while typing), you will come to same position you are typing with flickering of screen, so please help me in resolving the issue.

```
This is how my xml looks like,

    ScrollView          //My parent
    LinearLayout         //Direct child
        Editext           //1
          rest of editext
        Editext            //20
       LinearLayout
    ScrollView
```

I just want to remove flickering of screen in android...i had tried my effort to do but failed.