# AutoCompleteTextView and input type in Android

Tags: android

When I give inputtype as "TextUri" for AutoCompleteTextView, the keyboard shows up and after entering the url when I click on Done, instead of going away it's still getting displayed in the screen..

To hide the keyboard,I need to press backbutton..

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textUri"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the link below might be helpful, it basically says use this:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
  inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

[how to hide keyboard after typing in EditText in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342620/how-to-hide-keyboard-after-typing-in-edittext-in-android)