# How to hide the keyboard, and add text to EditText and move the cursor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button, android-cursor

I have an `EditText` and a `Button`. When you press `EditText`, I want to not show the `keyboard`, And when you press the `Button`, I want to type a number 1 on the `EditText`.

The observation I want to `cursor` does not disappear.

[When you press the 1 1 writes
When you press the Del licked
Can be controlled in the text
Without the appearance of the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pMNA.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342620/how-to-hide-keyboard-after-typing-in-edittext-in-android

Comment: you can use `setCursorVisible(false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these codes:

```
your_edit_text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            your_edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            EditText.setText("1");
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
             your_edit_text.setSelection(your_edit_text.getText().length()); // move cursor to end
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Karim Michel.** You can use

For First Case .Hide Keyboard

```
   ETOBJ.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
            {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS); 
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And when Press on Button you can use

```
setCursorVisible(false);
setText("1");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963763/how-to-detect-when-button-pressed-and-released-on-android

Comment: I want to not show the keyboard
I want to control the text by button